# Cookie setcookie is not reflecting

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to set cookie using API CookieManager in webview for sencha page.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookie);
```

But session is not reflecting when page is loading in webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working bit of code.

```
    private void setCookie(DefaultHttpClient httpClient, String url) {
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            Cookie cookie = cookies.get(i);
            String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue();
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookieString);
        }
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
}
```

Here the httpclient is the DefaultHttpClient object you used in the HttpGet/HttpPost request. Also one thing to make sure is the cookie name and value, it should be given

```
String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue();
```

setCookie will the set the cookie for the given URL.